# PHP PDO Login return bool(false)

Tags: php, pdo, authentication

I am making a login for my website, but when i enter the name & pass in the form it gives a bool(false) back. Can't find out why it's happening. I've used the same code for another website with some adjustments and its just working fine there.

```
//classDatabase.php
class Database
{
    public $pdo = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
      $db_user = '******';
      $db_pass = '*******';

      $this->pdo = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=showcase_nl', $db_user, $db_pass );
    }

    public function getDb()
    {
      return $this->pdo;
    }

    public function getLogin($name, $pass)
    {
      $sql = "SELECT id, name, pass FROM users WHERE name=:name AND pass=:pass";
      $query = $this->getDb()->prepare($sql);
      $query->execute(array(':name'=>$name, ':pass'=>$pass ));
      $result = $query->fetch();
      return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

**Login.php**

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
  $name = isset($_POST[ 'name' ]) ? $_POST[ 'name' ] : '';
  $pass = isset($_POST[ 'pass' ]) ? $_POST[ 'pass' ] : '';

  if ($name != '' && $pass != '')
  {
      $result = $db->getLogin($name, $pass);
      if (count($result) > 0)
      {
          $_SESSION['login'] = $result;

          var_dump($_SESSION);

          if ($_SESSION['login'])
          {
              header('Location: ?page=beheer.php');
          }
          else
          {
            echo 'Gegevens zijn onjuist';
          }
      }
      else
      {
          echo 'Onbekende gebruiker';
      }
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'Je hebt niet alle velden ingevuld';
  }
}
else
{
  echo '
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <div class="panel-blog panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
              <form method="post">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name">Naam:</label>
                  <input type="name" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Naam">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="pass">Wachtwoord:</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Wachtwoord">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Log in</button>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>';
}
```

Also tried it with PDOStatement::bindParam, but still doesn't work.

```
public function getLogin($name, $pass)
{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name=:name AND pass=:pass";
  $query = $this->getDb()->prepare($sql);
  $query->bindParam(':name', $name);
  $query->bindParam(':pass', $pass);
  $query->execute();
  $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried narrowing down where the issue might be? Do the variables get sent to the backend correctly? Are they still correct when they are used as variables in the query?

Comment: false is a valid return value for PDOStatement::fetch(), you should check PDO::errorInfo() to see, if there was a SQL error.

Comment: When i do that it returns this;
Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )
So it doesnt get the values from the database.. That strange..

Comment: Also if i just make a simple function what return the name & pass from my database it just works..

  public function getRow()
    {
      $sql = "SELECT name, pass FROM users";
      $query = $this->getDb()->prepare($sql);
      $query->execute();
      $result = $query->fetchAll();

      return $result;
    }

Comment: You should use `session_start()` at top of your Login.php before you create session. If table exactly return a row with your name and password values, it should work.

Comment: I already started the session in my index.php. In index.php i load my pages.